# How to force Rabbit MQ to accumulate and send messages again?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration

I have several Spring-Integration elements  configured in the XML file (see below)
From the amqp channel adapter the messages are directed to the router integrationSecondaryRouter  that has implementation  integrationRouterImpl.

If there is a not caught exception in integrationRouterImpl I expect that the Rabbit MQ will send the message again and again.  However, this does not happen. The Rabbit MQ monitor does not show any messages accumulation. An error in my configuration?

```
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter 
    channel="integrationFrontDoorQueueChannel" 
    queue-names="${integration.creation.orders.queue.name}" 
    header-mapper="integrationHeaderMapper"
    connection-factory="connectionFactory" 
    error-channel="errorChannel" 
/>

<int:chain 
        id="integrationFrontDoorQueueChain" 
        input-channel="integrationFrontDoorQueueChannel"
        output-channel="integrationRouterChannel">
    <int:transformer ref="integrationJsonPayloadTransformer" method="transformMessagePayload"/>
    <int:filter ref="integrationNonDigitalCancellationFilter" method="filter"/>
    <int:filter ref="integrationPartnerFilter" method="filter"/>
    <int:filter ref="integrationOrderDtoDgcAndGoSelectFilter" method="filter"/>

</int:chain>

 <int:header-value-router 
    id="integrationPrimaryRouter"
    input-channel="integrationRouterChannel" 
    default-output-channel="integrationFrontDoorRouterChannel"
    resolution-required="false"
    header-name="#{T(com.smartdestinations.constants.SdiConstants).INTEGRATION_PAYLOAD_ACTION_HEADER_KEY}">
    <int:mapping 
        value="#{T(com.smartdestinations.service.integration.dto.IntegrationAction).EXCLUSION_SCAN.name()}" 
        channel="integrationExclusionChannel" 
    />
</int:header-value-router>


<int:router 
        id="integrationSecondaryRouter"
        ref="integrationRouterImpl" 
        input-channel="integrationFrontDoorRouterChannel"
        method="route" 
        resolution-required="false" 
        default-output-channel="nullChannel"
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, you have `error-channel="errorChannel"` and the [Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler) on the matter points out:

> The default "errorChannel" is a PublishSubscribeChannel.

Yes, there is one subscriber. but it just `_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger`.

Since there is no anyone who re-throws your exception to the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`, thefore no reason to `nack` message and redelive it again.